# How to make Google Chrome download FLV instead of stream it?

Tags: google-chrome, download, flv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to download a video file in Google Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/17302/how-to-download-a-video-file-in-google-chrome)

When I open FLV file links in Chrome, it tries to stream it instead of prompting me to download. How do I make it so that when I view FLV links, I will be prompted to download? While streaming may be more convenient, I find that it's faster (for me) to just download it and play the physical .flv file locally.

I'm on a mac, snow leopard.

Comment: Right-click -> "Save link as..."?

Comment: Possible duplicate yes, but no accepted answer though. :/

Comment: @DanielAndersson, it has to go through session handlers so I will only get redirected to the FLV file. I don't have a physical link directly to it. Otherwise, I'd have done what you said ages ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't so much the actual downloading.  It's the session handlers.  So, just side step them.

Are you talking about getting videos off YouTube?  Use the [Chrome extension for downloading video from Youtube](http://www.chromeextensions.org/music-videos-photos/download-youtube-videos-as-mp4-flv-webm/) and saving as FLV.

There's also an [extension for just downloading FLV video](http://www.chromeextensions.org/utilities/flash-video-download/), but it's made for developers builds of Chrome.

And... here's a [flash video downloader for Chrome](http://download.cnet.com/Flash-Video-Downloader-for-Google-Chrome/3000-33362_4-75327988.html)... hosted on Cnet.

So, there are options.  Not so much changing the behavior of Chrome, but more about changing your behavior... in what you do when you find a video you want to watch.

Comment: I found out that all I had to do to get the behavior I was wanting was to disable the QuickTime plugin. I figured this out when I was fiddling with the settings after I posted this question. But thanks anyway.